# Unity material set gives purple color in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to set the colors in runtime in Unity. When I set, it returns a purple color instead. Following is the code in my start method;

```
Material testMaterial= Resources.Load("Assets/Colors/front/LA.mat", typeof(Material)) as Material;

objectRenderer.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = testMaterial;
```

[image]

I  develop my game in **Unity URP** and material apply to **both side** of the game object. I can do it manually by drag and drop but I wanted to automate it. When I do it with C# script, I get this purple color. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: That’s not purple!!  However. That is a sign of unity saying missing material or the material is not right for urp. Eg it was designed for the standard legacy stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a new folder called "Resources".
Unity understands your path like "Resources/Assets/Colors/front/LA.mat", but there's no Resources folder in your project.
Just create Resources folder and move all assets you need to load at runtime to it.
But be careful and not move all the assets to this folder because these resources will be included in build even if you are not using them, so this may cause build size grow.

Comment: creating a Resources folder helps!

Comment: I set like this: "Resources/Colors/front/LA".. it works now! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the material to the Resources folder?

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html